# How to customize shape of Material-UI tab indicator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to turn the *material-ui* tab indicator into a triangle. At the moment, I can only manipulate the indicator into differently sized rectangles/squares. Is it possible to change it into an arrow or an upside down triangle?

**Here is what I have so far:**
[image: red square is indicator]

Here is the code for the indicator:

```
TabIndicatorProps={{
                style: {
                  alignSelf: "flex-start",
                  height: "15px",
                  width: "15px",
                  transform: "translateY(-100px)",
                  backgroundImage: ArrowDropDownIcon,
                  backgroundColor: "#CC0202",
                  marginLeft: "6px",
                },
              }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the icon, you could create a triangle using CSS and I think it would give the same result you are looking for:

```
<Tabs
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      borderLeft: "10px solid transparent",
      borderRight: "10px solid transparent",
      borderTop: "10px solid #f00",
      transform: "translateY(-100px)",
      alignSelf: "flex-start",
      marginLeft: "5px",
    },
  }}
  indicatorColor='primary.main'
>
```

[image: Example of Indicator with triangle styling]

---

edit:

There is also another way to do this which I think is better since it removes the dependency on borders and pixels, and you have more freedom with your shapes:

```
TabIndicatorProps={{
  style: {
    top: theme.spacing(2),
    height: 10, 
    width: 12,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: "#be0000",
    clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%)',
  },
}}
```

Also, since this version uses the clip path, which makes it so the background color only applies in the shape, there is no need to set the `indicatorColor` to the color your background.

I also replaced some of the formatting being done with pixels to use theme.spacing instead. It should help it be more responsive.

[image: Tab Indicator with Custom Shape V2]